# c++ clear the contents of a file after a specific position

Tags: c++, qt, file-io, truncate, fstream

I would like to use either `fstream` or preferably `QFile` to remove the contents of a file **after** a specific position (that's not the beginning or the end of the file). So I first jump to that position with `QFile::seek(long)` or equivalent in [constant time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171403/qfile-seek-performance/6171433), and then I would like to remove the remainder of the content, also in constant time. What approach do you recommend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `QFile::resize` to resize the file to the size you want. I bet it uses `truncate` behind the scenes (see Andrew's post).

Answer (score 3):

Lookup...

```
#include <unistd.h>
int ftruncate(int fildes, off_t length);
int truncate(const char *path, off_t length);
```

A quick snip from this [site](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/ftruncate.html) yielded...

> If the file previously was larger than length, the extra data is discarded.

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873454/how-to-truncate-a-file-in-c/873653#873653) interesting.

Comment: Your answer is technically correct (and what I thought about writing at first), but the OP asked for a `QFile`-based solution. Thankfully, there is one.

Comment: Fair enough, I knew this would work so I included it. I also didn't know resize used truncate so you'll get a +1 for me. I'll also leave this answer since it is valid though not optimal.

Comment: Great answer, but yes, the `QFile::resize` answer does address what I was looking for. Thank you! +1

Answer (score 0):

Consider the new position, after the `seek()`, to be the end of the file. When you're done working with the file write everything from the start up until that point.