# Complexity of f.seek() in Python

Tags: python, file, io, big-o, fseek

Does `f.seek(500000,0)` go through all the first 499999 characters of the file before getting to the 500000th?
In other words, is `f.seek(n,0)` of order O(n) or O(1)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to be a bit more specific on what type of object `f` is.

If `f` is a normal [`io` module](https://docs.python.org/library/io.html) object for a file stored on disk, you have to determine if you are dealing with:

- The raw binary file object
- A buffer object, wrapping the raw binary file
- A TextIO object, wrapping the buffer
- An in-memory `BytesIO` or `TextIO` object

The first option just uses the [`lseek` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) to reposition the file descriptor position. If this call is O(1) depends on the OS and what kind of file system you have. For a Linux system with ext4 filesystem, [`lseek` is O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658364/is-lseek-o1-complexity).

Buffers just clear the buffer [if your seek target is outside of the current buffered region](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fc46979b8c802675ca7fd51c6f2108a305001c8/Modules/_io/bufferedio.c#L1259-L1306) and read in new buffer data. That's O(1) too, but the fixed cost is higher.

For text files, things are more complicated as variable-byte-length codecs and line-ending translation mean you can't always map the binary stream position to a text position without scanning from the start. The implementation doesn't allow for non-zero current-position- or end-relative seeks, and does it's best to minimise how much data is read for absolute seeks. [Internal state shared with the text decoder](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fc46979b8c802675ca7fd51c6f2108a305001c8/Modules/_io/textio.c#L2190-L2198) tracks a [recent 'safe point' to seek back to](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fc46979b8c802675ca7fd51c6f2108a305001c8/Modules/_io/textio.c#L2425-L2502) and read forward to the desired position. Worst-case this is O(n).

The in-memory file objects are just long, addressable arrays really. Seeking is O(1) because you can just alter the current position pointer value.

There are legion other file-like objects that may or may not support seeking. How they handle seeking is implementation dependent.

- The [`zipfile` module](https://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) supports seeking on zip files opened in read-only mode, and seeking to a point that lies before the data section covered by the current buffer requires a full re-read and decompression of the data up to the desired point, seeking after requires reading from the current position until you reach the new. The [`gzip`](https://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html), [`lzma`](https://docs.python.org/library/lzma.html) and [`bz2`](https://docs.python.org/library/bz2.html) modules all use the [same shared implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fc46979b8c802675ca7fd51c6f2108a305001c8/Lib/_compression.py), that also [starts reading from the start if you seek to a point before the current read position](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/72ce82abcf9051b18a05350936de7ecab7306662/Lib/_compression.py#L135-L139) (and there's no larger buffer to avoid this).
- The [`chunk` module](https://docs.python.org/library/chunk.html) allows seeking within the chunk boundaries and delegates to the underlying object. This is an O(1) operation if the underlying file seek operation is O(1).

Etc. So, *it depends*.

Comment: Do you know if this applies to gzip.py also?

Comment: @jsmedmar I already include the `gzip` module in my answer, it shares a common base implementation with  the other compression formats and these have to do a full re-read of the compressed stream if you are seeking to a point before the current.

Comment: Is there a way to get `tell` and `seek` on the `gzip` file itself, and not on the underlying decompressed data?

Comment: @JohnStrood: the wrapped file object is available as [`gzipfileobj.fileobj`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/099e6a4096382697dda55d58d3a96f68375ea546/Lib/gzip.py#L209). Seeking on that object *will* beak the internal state of the read buffer, however.

Comment: @JohnStrood you can use `io.FileIO` to read the uncompressed data.

Comment: @Kenpachi that’s just the interface for file objects, the `.fileobj` attribute is such an object.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the implementation of f.  However, in normal file-system files, it is O(1).

If python implements f on text files, it could be implemented as O(n), as each character may need to be inspected to manage cr/lf pairs correctly.

- This would be based on whether `f.seek(n,0)` gave the same result as a loop of reading chars, and (depending on OS) cr/lf were shrunk to lf or lf expanded to cr/lf

If python implements f on a compressed stream,  then the order would b O(n), as decompression may require some working of blocks, and decompression.

Comment: `However, in normal file-system files, it is O(1).` This seems very wrong.

Comment: Time should not depend on `n` in terms of big-O, however, I'd expect if `n` is close enough to the current offset, seek would not cause any disk access.

Comment: @mksteve: I was wrong, `zipfile.ZipFile` does support seeking when reading, and it'll try to satisfy that from the current buffer. If it can't it'll seek back to compression section start and re-read data until it reaches the desired position.

Comment: `seek` itself is almost certainly O(1), because any further work can (and should) be delayed until a read or write actually *needs* the new file position. No sense doing an O(N) operation if the next operation on the file is a close.