# Implementing a database in a single file

Tags: database, fs, flat-file, inode

This question is about creating a new single file database format. I am new to this!

I wonder how SQLite does this- for databases larger than the available memory, SQLite must be reading from certain parts of the file somehow, i.e. reading at position n?

Is this possible at sub-linear runtime complexity? I assume that when SQLite fetches a particular row, it uses a O(logn) index lookup first- so it doesn't fetch the entire index- and then it fetches the row from a particular location in the file. All of this involves not reading the whole file into memory- but FS methods appear not to provide this functionality.

Is fs.skip(n) [pseudocode] done in O(n) or does the OS skip straight to position n? Theoretically this should be possible because in the OS files are divided into blocks- and inodes reference 1-3 levels of array-like structures that locate the blocks, so fetching a particular block in a file should be possible in sub-linear time- without reading in the entire file.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801213/complexity-of-f-seek-in-python

Comment: @Ry- thank you, this answers my question!

Answer (score -3):

> I wonder how SQLite does this- for databases larger than the available memory, SQLite
> must be reading from certain parts of the file somehow, i.e. reading at position n?

Yes. Almost every programming language has documentation that explains how to position the read on a file.

> All of this involves not reading the whole file into memory- but FS methods appear not to
> provide this functionality.

Every file system access API that I know of *does* support this, and it is explained in the documentation. Examples range from memory-mapped files in Windows (which are "quite" advanced and not supported if you plan to go OS-agnostic), down to something simple like the `fseek()` method in C that positions a file stream.

I suggest brushing up on your knowledge of file-system access methods in your programming language of choice.

Comment: Here's one programming language documentation that doesn't let you position the read on a file: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_read_file

Comment: No, that one is a demonstration of you not reading the documentation. May I bluntly point you to fs.read that has a position parameter allowing you to specify where in the file you start reading.